# Is it possible to allow many users to make live broadcasts using YouTube API and a single account?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to make a web application and I want to use YouTube API to allow my users make live broadcasts.

Is it necessary that my users log with their Google/YouTube accounts to use the live stream or is it possible to make them use this function without bothering them with this detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the Live Event and Live Stream objects required for a livestream on YouTube, the user making those requests must be authenticated.

From the Docs:

> Your application must have authorization credentials to be able to use the YouTube Live Streaming API.

Obtaining authorization credentials guide [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/registering_an_application).

Adding a live event is similar to uploading a video.  The user making the upload must be authenticated in order for the video to appear on their channel.

Comment: in short, the answer is no ... you cannot allow another user to live broadcast through your channel.