# Livestream on some one else youtube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, youtube-data-api

I am able to live stream video on my youtube channel. 
But is it possible that whoever use my app signup with their google account and, able to stream video on one particular youtube channel?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to allow many users to make live broadcasts using YouTube API and a single account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535840/is-it-possible-to-allow-many-users-to-make-live-broadcasts-using-youtube-api-and).  The answer is no.